# По какому принципу группируются баллы в откатах голосования?

Tags: поддержка, голоса-против

Почему отмена отображается двумя записями?

[image: Голосование исправлено]

и на день раньше:
[image: Голосование исправлено]

Отмены относятся к этому [вопросу](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522931/178988) и ответам на него.

С [комментарием](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522931/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-javascript-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c#comment647470_522931)

> @Qwertiy у меня откатило 3 из 4 голосов. Отобразилось как три "+1" в нотификациях - примерно так. Решения на мете по голосам не выносятся (к сожалению, или к счастью). – PashaPash ♦

тоже как-то не очень совпадает - если бы по сообщениям - должно было бы быть минимум 3 записи, а если по пользователям - то одно из значений должно быть +6, но есть только +10 и +12. Какой ещё критерий может использоваться для разделения?

Comment: Тип записи? Вопрос или ответ, скажем.